# Dynamic width view with subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to create the following in a xib:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIdu6.jpg

Please ignore the poor drawing. Basically, the black border is the main view. Inside that main view, I have a smaller view (in blue) that should be on the right side of the main view, centered vertically. The blue view also has a label as a subview, so I need the blue view to have a dynamic width based on the length of the label.

However, I can't seem to get the constraints right. Every time, I get red constraints and errors. What would the correct constraints for this be?

Comment: some code, or a screenshot of your storyboard could help

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at my computer right now

Comment: stackview will help you

Comment: @karthikeyan To my knowledge, you cannot set a background to StackView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give below three `constraints`

- Vertically center to it `superview`
- Constant trailing space.
- Leading constrain with `>=` value to specify the value of x

**Storyboard constraints:**

[image: Storyboard constraints]

[Download demo code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r93Jsspdh4BiYE8o0Je9nzhdNt_He_YX)